# Connect to WMI of remote machine when running as a service

Tags: c++, wmi

I am writing some code to do wmi query and method execution on remote machine. My login credential is a domain admin. When I run in application mode, every works fine. When I run as service, it won't work which is expected since the default account service uses isLocal System. When I set the service to run as my credential, the remote wmi is working fine as well.

However it is not desirable, so I am trying to connect to remote wmi at service by supplying the user name and password at IWbemLocator.ConnectServer. I am able to get a IWbemServices object back successfully. However when I tried to Get the class object from the IWbemServices object, I got error:

```
//IWbemServices *pSvc
const bstr_t objectPath("stdRegProv");
const bstr_t methodName("GetStringValue");
IWbemClassObject *pClass = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pSvc->GetObject(objectPath, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
```

The returned hr is 0x80041003 which is "access is denied" from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Generally if I supplied the wrong user name and password, I would get the access denied at the IWbemLocator.ConnectServer. So I am a little puzzled here why connection is good however I am not able to get the IWbemClassObject object. Since it is working if I use my domain credential as the service account, there must be some security difference. My WMI connection code is based on this sample code at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I opened another post on the Microsoft forum: [MS Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/4161d6a1-1b52-4aa9-98b9-eacad5ba2a90/) where it goes much deeper on this issue. However it is still not resolved.

Comment: Are you using IWbemLocator.ConnectServer to connect from the remote server to a third host?

Answer (score 1):

WMI kind of strips some security rights; you need to either set up your account as "Trusted for delegation", which is *extremely* powerful and not recommended, or sign your code. Alternatively you can pass explicit permissions to the process.

Comment: You sure they need to supply delegation priv and not just impersonation?  Not 100% sure on this, but that's what occurs to me.

Comment: I would normally agree with you, Kevin, but the code he referenced uses impersonation. If the user didn't fully or properly implement it then updating his code with impersonation would be a good idea. :)

Comment: vote you up for your help here. However at this point, I don't have an env to confirm this any more. Basically we didn't go remote wmi route.